How to load pre-trained models without having to load Flux.jl?
I have a pre-trained neural network which I want to use it without having to load Flux.jl because it takes some seconds to load flux.jl. Should I write the model again without having to load Flux.jl?
Is it faster or not?
I don't have a GPU.
I want to use the model as an application, so I don't want to load whole of Flux.jl.

You have a few options.
Recent versions of Julia support precompilation, so loading a package that has been precompiled should take very little time (this answer the question of @Christoph-Rackwitz too).
If this is still an issue, you can use instead of the simple julia executable a compiled bundle "julia+packages that you need" (or julia executable + a sysimage of the fully compiled packages) that you can make with PackageCompiler.jl
Finally, if all you want is a predict function and the model is simple enought, you can manually recode the model using standard arrays and use the saved weigths as part of the arrays you multiply your data to.

Well, you can't. Julia needs time to precompile packages and run tests for them. Since environment can be dynamic, this happens every time when Julia starts. This used to take more time in previous versions.
julia> @time using Flux
  3.352512 seconds (2.85 M allocations: 185.943 MiB, 9.58% gc time, 4.57% compilation time: 30% of which was recompilation)

Yet Julia used 4.57% time on compilation. So the problem might be memory allocation in Flux.jl package?

does it have to do this even when the same program is run repeatedly back to back on the same machine without any changes to any of the environment?
